# Error while web service call to salesforce sandbox

Tags: java, salesforce, endpoint

I am integrating with salesforce through java. 
 I want to test it on salesforce sandbox so i am using END POINT as  : `https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/21.0`

```
ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
config.setUsername(LoginHelper.userName);
config.setPassword(LoginHelper.password);
config.setServiceEndpoint(LoginHelper.END_POINT);
PartnerConnection pCon = Connector.newConnection(config);
```

but i get an error like : `Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.`

Please help!

Comment: Are you sure, that the error isn't exactly what's wrong? Have you tried logging in to the test instance using the username/password you supplied to the client?

Comment: Yes i am able to login to the test instance.

Comment: Then show some code. Maybe we can figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Sure 
 
 `   ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
  config.setUsername(LoginHelper.userName);
  config.setPassword(LoginHelper.password);
  config.setServiceEndpoint(LoginHelper.END_POINT);
  PartnerConnection pCon = Connector.newConnection(config);`

Comment: I have added your code to your question. Please update the question instead of adding comments for stuff like that. (You can find the edit link below the tags)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to use `config.setAuthEndpoint()` instead of `config.setServiceEndpoint()`.